# Interoperating between CM Synergy and Mercurial

Tags: mercurial, cm-synergy

Is it possible to push and maybe pull from Mercurial(Hg) to CM synergy. For instance we have a main server where all source control and related tasks are done using CM Synergy. I have a private mercurial repository that is local to my machine, at some point I would like to push my work up from my hg repository to the main CM Synergy server. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to pull down the latest from cmsynergy when you are ready to do a push. Then copy all the files you changed in mercurial into the cmsynergy work area. In cmsynergy do a "sync with work area" and select keep work area changes. This is the simplest way I have found with the version of cmsynergy my company uses. Some of the older versions have a reconcile command which can make this a bit easier, but has some control issues.